# Why will the class Car store the correct information for objects car and car2 but the class Owner won't store information for the object owner2?

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm new-ish to Java. I'm sorry this is so long. Directly below is the **output of my code so far** The part with ** is where I'm having a problem. I'm supposed to be comparing the speeds of two Car objects, but each Owner object is either a "safe" or "rash" driver. If they are rash, when they accelerate they speed up by 10. If they are safe, they speed up by 5. So far that aspect is working, however, only the first Owner object will store information. So whatever the first Owner object is (Safe/rash) they will both be. This isn't occurring for my Car objects, as each separate object is storing the correct information which is where I'm having difficulty. Can anyone help me figure out why?

```
Car Name: Betty
Year: 2002
Car Make: Kia
Car Model: Soul
Car Mileage: 50000
Car Speed: 65
Car owner name: Jane
Car owner type: rash
Car Name: Duke
Year: 2002
Car Make: Ford
Car Model: F250
Car Mileage: 50000
Car Speed: 65
Car owner name: John
Car owner type: safe


Betty is a 2002 Kia Soul.
The current mileage is 50000 and current speed is 65.
Jane is the owner of the car and is a rash driver.

Duke is a 2002 Ford F250.
The current mileage is 50000 and current speed is 65.
**Jane is the owner of the car and is a rash driver.**

The total mileage of both cars is 100000
Betty is going 75.
**Duke is going 75.**
```

This is what I have for class Car:

```
class Car{

//---INSTANCE VARIABLES---
private String carName;
private int yearModel;
private String make;
private String model;
private int speed;
private int mileage;
private Owner carOwner;
private static int totalMileage;


//---CAR CONSTRUCTOR---
public Car(String n, int y, String ma, String m, int ml, int s, Owner o) {
    carName = n;
    yearModel = y;
    make = ma;
    model = m;
    speed = s;
    mileage = ml;
    carOwner = o;
    totalMileage += ml;
}

//---MUTATOR & ACCESSOR METHODS---

public void setName(String n) {
    carName = n;
}
public String getName() {
    return carName;
}

public void setYearModel(int y) {
    yearModel = y;
}
public int getYear() {
    return yearModel;
}

public void setMake(String ma) {
    make = ma;
}
public String getMake() {
    return make;
}

public void setModel(String m) {
    model = m;
}
public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setSpeed(int s) {
    speed = s;
}
public int getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}

public void setMileage(int ml) {
    mileage = ml;
}
public int getMileage() {
    return mileage;
}

public void setOwnerName(Owner n) {
    carOwner = n;
}
public Owner getOwnerName() {
    return carOwner;
}

//---ACCELERATE()---

public void accelerate() {
    if(carOwner.getOwnType().equalsIgnoreCase("rash")) {
        speed += 10;
    } else {
        speed += 5;
    }
}
//---BRAKE---

public void brake() {
    if(speed == 0) {
        System.out.println("You are already stopped!");
    } else {
        speed -= 5;
    }//end if-else statement
}

//---COMPARE()---

public void compare() {

}

//---TOSTRING()---

public String toString() {
    String response = "";
    response += "\n\n"+ carName +" is a " + yearModel + " " + make + " " + model+ ".";
    response += "\nThe current mileage is " + mileage + " and current speed is " + speed;
    response += ".\n" + carOwner.toString();
    return response;
}

//---TOTALMILEAGE---

public static int getTotalMileage() {
    return totalMileage;
}

}//---END CLASS CAR
```

class Owner:

```
public class Owner {

private String ownName;
private String ownType;

public Owner (String ownerName, String ownerType) {
    ownName = ownerName;
    ownType = ownerType;
}

public void setOwnType(String ownerType) {
    ownType = ownerType;
}
public String getOwnType() {
    return ownType;
}

public void setOwnName(String ownerName) {
    ownName = ownerName;
}
public String getOwnName() {
    return ownName;
}

public String toString() {
    return ownName + " is the owner of the car and is a " + ownType + " driver.";
}


 }//end Owner class
```

This is where my main method is:

```
import java.util.*;
public class carDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car car = null;
    Owner owner = null;
    Car car2 = null;
    Owner owner2 = null;
    String carName, make, model, ownerName, ownerType;
    int yearModel, speed, mileage;


    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        System.out.print("Car Name: ");
        carName = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Year: ");
        yearModel = kb.nextInt();
        kb.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Car Make: ");
        make = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Car Model: ");
        model = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Car Mileage: ");
        mileage = kb.nextInt();
        kb.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Car Speed: ");
        speed = kb.nextInt();
        kb.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Car owner name: ");
        ownerName = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Car owner type: ");
        ownerType = kb.nextLine();

        if(i == 2) {
            owner2 = new Owner(ownerName, ownerType);
            car2 = new Car(carName, yearModel, make, model, mileage, speed, owner);
        } else {
        owner = new Owner(ownerName, ownerType);
        car = new Car(carName, yearModel, make, model, mileage, speed, owner);

        }

    } //end for loop

        System.out.print(car);
        System.out.print(car2);
        System.out.println("\n\nThe total mileage of both cars is " + Car.getTotalMileage());

        car.accelerate();
        car2.accelerate();
        System.out.println(car.getName() + " is going " +      car.getSpeed() + ".");
        System.out.println(car2.getName() + " is going " + car2.getSpeed() + ".");




} //end main

} //end carDemo
```

Comment: if(i == 2) {
            owner2 = new Owner(ownerName, ownerType);
            car2 = new Car(carName, yearModel, make, model, mileage, speed, owner2); //change is here
        }

Comment: I'm super annoyed I couldn't spot this myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `car` and `car2` gets the same `owner` instance in the constructor. One of them should be `owner2`.

```
car2 = new Car(carName, yearModel, make, model, mileage, speed, owner2);
                                                           // here ^
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I wish I had enough points to upvote you, kind stranger.